# How to map multiple source members so that propertyMap.SourceMembers yields these multiple source members?

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to reuse the intialized mappings of the c# Automapper (using version 6.2.2) by looping through all mapped properties.

Let's suppose I have the following:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.FullName, 
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName + " " + src.LastName));
};
```

The loop for `Id` behaves as expected:

```
var map = AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor<Person, PersonDto>();
foreach (var propertyMap in map.GetPropertyMaps())
{
    var destProp = propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name; // = "Id"
    var sourceMember = propertyMap.SourceMember.Name; // = "Id"
    var sourceMembers = propertyMap.SourceMembers; // Count = 1
}
```

But when I loop through the `FullName` property mapping, I want to achieve that the propertyMap.SourceMembers results in the two SourceMembers `FirstName` and `LastName`:

```
var map = AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor<Person, PersonDto>();
foreach (var propertyMap in map.GetPropertyMaps())
{
    var destProp = propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name; // = "FullName"
    var sourceMember = propertyMap.SourceMember.Name; // = "LastName" (I don't care)
    var sourceMembers = propertyMap.SourceMembers; // Count = 0 (want to achieve 2 for FirstName and LastName)
}
```

My goal is to create an automated similar mapping for an `orderBy` functionality based on the initialized automapper mappings. So I need to know (a) the order and (b) the sourceMembers. In the above case I want get the mapping for `FullName` from its source members `FirstName` and `LastName` (in this order).

Is it somehow possible to correctly register multiple source members so that `propertyMap.SourceMembers` yields all mapped source members? If yes, what should the map initialization look like?

PS: I don't want to write the orderBy mappings by hand, since I already have mappings thanks to automapper.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/88a7c788124c184ca570d21f4dda4da32cb17a3b/src/AutoMapper/Internal/MemberVisitor.cs#L10

Comment: I didn't find smth that does exactly what you need, but that's the idea. Have a visitor that accumulates MemberExpression-s.

Comment: Thank you for the link Lucian Bargaoanu, I think I know where to go now :-) I'll post my answer as soon as I have a robust solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lucian Bargaoanu, I developed the following *dirty* workaround.

Please note that this is the first time that I get in touch with interpreting expressions, so bear with me the quality of my solution:

```
var map = AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor<Person, PersonDto>();
foreach (var propertyMap in map.PropertyMaps)
{
    var destProp = propertyMap.DestinationMember.Name; // = "FullName"
    var sourceMember = propertyMap.SourceMember?.Name; // = "LastName" (I don't care)
    var sourceMembers = propertyMap.SourceMembers.ToList();
    if (sourceMembers.Count() == 0)
    {
        ResolveSourceMembersInOrder(sourceMembers,
            propertyMap.CustomMapExpression.Body as BinaryExpression);
    }

    // sourceMembers now yield the two desired sourceMembers "FirstName" and "LastName"
}

public static void ResolveSourceMembersInOrder(List<MemberInfo> memberInfos, BinaryExpression expression)
{
    if (memberInfos == null)
    {
        memberInfos = new List<MemberInfo>();
    }

    if (expression == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var left = expression.Left;
    if (left.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
        memberInfos.Add(MemberVisitor.GetMemberPath(left).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    else
    {
        ResolveSourceMembersInOrder(memberInfos, left as BinaryExpression);
    }

    var right = expression.Right;
    if (right.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
    {
        memberInfos.Add(MemberVisitor.GetMemberPath(right).FirstOrDefault());
    }
    else
    {
        ResolveSourceMembersInOrder(memberInfos, right as BinaryExpression);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/dd769ffcdbca263024c19d0ae1ebd3ad). It returns things in the right order, but a few tests wouldn't hurt :)